# Birds don't get electrocuted on live wire

Tags: electrical-resistance

Why is birds which stay on electrical wire which current is being pass through doesn't get shock?

Answer (score 1):

Because they always sit on a single wire, they do not touch two wires at a time. Just touching one wire does not complete the circuit and they do not get electrocuted. The voltage difference between their feet on the same wire may be negligible even if the wires are not insulated.